# Python: PDF: How to read from form elements like checkbox

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I've created a form with Reportlab API in python, e.g. with some checkboxes.

```
# simple_checkboxes.py

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, pink, blue, green

def create_simple_checkboxes():
    c = canvas.Canvas('simple_checkboxes2.pdf')

    #c.setFont("Courier", 20)
    c.drawCentredString(300, 700, 'Pets')
    #c.setFont("Courier", 14)
    form = c.acroForm

    c.drawString(10, 650, 'Dog:')
    form.checkbox(name='cb1', tooltip='Field cb1',
                  x=110, y=645)

    c.drawString(10, 600, 'Cat:')
    form.checkbox(name='cb2', tooltip='Field cb2',
                  x=110, y=595)

    c.drawString(10, 550, 'Pony:')
    form.checkbox(name='cb3', tooltip='Field cb3',
                  x=110, y=545)

    c.drawString(10, 500, 'Python:')
    form.checkbox(name='cb4', tooltip='Field cb4',
                  x=110, y=495)

    c.drawString(10, 450, 'Hamster:')
    form.checkbox(name='cb5', tooltip='Field cb5',
                  x=110, y=445, checked=True)                  

    c.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_simple_checkboxes()
```

Now, how could I read the input from the PDF later on with Python, filled out by the user?
I have found no examples or documentation on the Reportlab API.

Or is there a better or simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no solution with reportlab...
But you can use PyPDF2 :)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import json

def getcheckboxes(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as pdf:
        pdfr = PdfFileReader(pdf)

        pdf_fields = pdfr.getFields() #get field content of PDF File
        rp = str(pdf_fields).replace("'", '"') #replace single quote with doudble to load string to dict
        boxes = json.loads(rp) # string -> dict
        for box in boxes: #loop over all checkboxes
            print("checkbox {0} value is {1}".format(boxes[box]["/T"], boxes[box]["/V"])) #print out name = /T attribute and checked attribite = /V


getcheckboxes("test.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't get it. :'( How would I read from radio buttons and input edits in addition?

Comment: then please ceate a new question :D and link it please :=)
basicly check out PyPDF2 :) https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/

Comment: i have updated my code with commets for better understanding @ProfP30

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This somehow helped. I have created a new questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812539/python-pdf-how-to-read-from-a-form-with-radio-buttons