# Python: PDF: How to read from a form with radio buttons

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I have created a form with some radio buttons, following the examples from [Creating Interactive PDF Forms in ReportLab with Python](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/05/29/creating-interactive-pdf-forms-in-reportlab-with-python/)

Here is code example esp. for radios:

## simple_radios.py

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, pink, blue, green

def create_simple_radios():
    c = canvas.Canvas('simple_radios.pdf')

    c.setFont("Courier", 20)
    c.drawCentredString(300, 700, 'Radio demo')
    c.setFont("Courier", 14)
    form = c.acroForm

    c.drawString(10, 650, 'Dog:')
    form.radio(name='radio1', tooltip='Field radio1',
               value='value1', selected=False,
               x=110, y=645, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=magenta, fillColor=pink, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)
    form.radio(name='radio1', tooltip='Field radio1',
               value='value2', selected=True,
               x=110, y=645, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=magenta, fillColor=pink, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)    

    c.drawString(10, 600, 'Cat:')
    form.radio(name='radio2', tooltip='Field radio2',
               value='value1', selected=True,
               x=110, y=595, buttonStyle='cross',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='circle',
               borderColor=green, fillColor=blue, 
               borderWidth=2,
               textColor=pink, forceBorder=True)
    form.radio(name='radio2', tooltip='Field radio2',
               value='value2', selected=False,
               x=110, y=595, buttonStyle='cross',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='circle',
               borderColor=green, fillColor=blue, 
               borderWidth=2,
               textColor=pink, forceBorder=True)

    c.drawString(10, 550, 'Pony:')
    form.radio(name='radio3', tooltip='Field radio3',
               value='value1', selected=False,
               x=110, y=545, buttonStyle='star',
               borderStyle='bevelled', shape='square',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=green, 
               borderWidth=2,
               textColor=magenta, forceBorder=False)
    form.radio(name='radio3', tooltip='Field radio3',
               value='value2', selected=True,
               x=110, y=545, buttonStyle='star',
               borderStyle='bevelled', shape='circle',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=green, 
               borderWidth=2,
               textColor=magenta, forceBorder=True)

    c.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_simple_radios()
```

My problem/question with that code is:
1.) The radios are always in a "pushed" state. How can I unpush them?
2.) Can the be grouped, so that only ONE (1) radio button is pushed according to a group
3.) How could I read the state of the buttons later on programmatically e.g. via PyPDF2?

Versions:

Python: 3.7.3
Reportlab: 3.5.19
Pillow: 6.0.0
PyPDF2: 1.26.0

OS:

Windows10 v1809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) The radios are always in a "pushed" state. How can I unpush them?

The buttons are pushed if `form.radio(... selected=True)`

> 2.) Can the be grouped, so that only ONE (1) radio button is pushed according to a group?

The `name` attribute is related to group name.

So `form.radio(... name="group1")` is one group `form.radio(... name="group2")` the second group. *You can only select one radio each group.*

So for the first two questions i've create a simple example with two different groups.
The first `group` contains `Fruits` and the second group contains `Cars`:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform
from reportlab.lib.colors import magenta, pink, blue, green, orange, yellow

def create_radios():
    c = canvas.Canvas('radios.pdf')

    c.setFont("Courier", 20)
    c.drawCentredString(300, 800, 'Radio demo')
    form = c.acroForm

    #GROUP ONE, name='group1'
    c.setFont("Courier", 16)
    c.drawString(10, 680, 'Fruits:')
    c.setFont("Courier", 12)
    c.drawString(10, 650, 'Apple:')
    form.radio(name='group1', tooltip='Apple',
               value='apple', selected=False,
               x=110, y=650, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=magenta, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)

    c.drawString(10, 600, 'Banana:')
    form.radio(name='group1', tooltip='Banana',
               value='banana', selected=False,
               x=110, y=600, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=yellow, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)

    c.drawString(10, 550, 'Orange:')
    form.radio(name='group1', tooltip='Orange',
               value='orange', selected=False,
               x=110, y=550, buttonStyle='check',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='square',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=orange, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=True)

    #GROUP TWO, name='group2'
    c.setFont("Courier", 16)
    c.drawString(210, 680, 'Cars:')
    c.setFont("Courier", 12)
    c.drawString(210, 650, 'Tesla:')
    form.radio(name='group2', tooltip='Apple',
               value='tesla', selected=False,
               x=310, y=650, buttonStyle='circle',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='circle',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=magenta, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=False)

    c.drawString(210, 600, 'Mercedes-Benz:')
    form.radio(name='group2', tooltip='Banana',
               value='mercedes', selected=False,
               x=310, y=600, buttonStyle='circle',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='circle',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=magenta, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=False)

    c.drawString(210, 550, 'Toyota:')
    form.radio(name='group2', tooltip='Orange',
               value='toyota', selected=False,
               x=310, y=550, buttonStyle='circle',
               borderStyle='solid', shape='circle',
               borderColor=blue, fillColor=magenta, 
               textColor=blue, forceBorder=False)

    c.save()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_radios()
```

> 3.) How could I read the state of the buttons later on programmatically e.g. via PyPDF2?

I have found a simpler approach then using PyPDF2 returned field data...

Using `pdfminer` will handle the problem well.

After i created the `radios.pdf` i changed the values using `Adobe` and saved it as new file `radios_checked.pdf` also you could change one `selected` attribute each group.

```
import sys
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

filename = "radios_checked.pdf"

with open(filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    parser = PDFParser(pdf_file)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name = str(field.get('T'), 'utf-8')

        value = field.get('V') #will return PSLiteral :/ 

        # transform PSLiteral to string
        if value != None:
            value = str(value)
            if value[0] == r"/":
                value = value[2:-1]
                value = str(value)

        print("Group Name: {0},  checked value: {1} ".format(name , value))
```

This will filter all group objects and print out selected group name and selected value.

Hint:
Open a `pdf` in texteditor and check the general structure.